# Can we save Feynman's martian rendez-vous with $CP$ violation?

Tags: standard-model, antimatter, cp-violation

There's a short part in *[The Feynman Lectures](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_52.html)* where he explains the why you should never shake a martian's left hand. He introduces a "martian" who we can only communicate with in some limited way, e.g. in binary. It ends with a warning: if you ever meet this martian and they try to shake your left hand, run away, they are made of antimatter!

To summarize the logic:

- If parity were an exact symmetry, there's no way to communicate the concept of "right" and "left". We could tell them to build a 2-way teleconference setup, and teach them how we greet each other with by shaking right hands, but we'd never know until we meet them that their monitory scans left to right, and our images were mirrored.
- This is solved somewhat by parity violating processes: decays that are preferentially aligned with the parent particle spin, for example, can be used to define a rotation axis, which can in turn be used to get a concept of clockwise and anti-clockwise, and thus right and left. So we can tell the martians to build this experiment and save them the awkwardness of bungling our most basic customs.
- The punchline is that, since most of these weak processes are $CP$-conserving, the martians can still get it wrong if they are made of antimatter. In the antimatter version of the same experiment were set up, we'd end up with an inverted version of left and right. So we still have our awkward encounter. And then we explode.

In this whole discussion, though, there is no discussion of $CP$-violating processes, and whether these could be used to figure out whether the martians were in fact describing a matter or antimatter experiment. Could you use a $CP$-violating process to save Fenyman's martian expedition?

Comment: Wait you think that "clockwise" wouldn't exist as a concept in a universe where the weak interactions are CP-conserving? Do I have that right? If so why? The functioning of a clock, and my ability to point at the clock and go "like that" does not depend on weak interactions in any way. My ability to construct large-scale objects with chirality does not depend on parity (or CP) violation in fundamental interactions.

Comment: It's worth noting that Feynman delivered his lectures from 1961–1964, during the brief historical moment between when P violation was discovered (1956) and when CP violation was discovered (1964).

Comment: Just for you to know, if you are searching for more about this, the problem is known as the Ozma problem.

Comment: @AXensen : everyone would be free to define clockwise and counterclockwise, left and right but no one would have a way to communicate it unless they could send e.g. a polarized signal. If they sent a series of 0s and 1s they could share videos or pictures of a clock, but how do they unpack into a pixel array? Saying "from right to left" won't do it if you're trying to define right and left.

Comment: @Shep why was it astonishing to physicists then when P violation was discovered in weak interactions? And even more astonishing when CP violation was discovered in neutral kaon decays. Shouldn't physicists have always known, according to you, just from the fact that clockwise is a definable concept, that CP is obviously violated?

Comment: You asked two questions: 1) because we'd never seen P violation before. 2) No. Going back to your first three questions in your first comment: 1) "Clockwise" would still exist without PC violation. 2&3) No you didn't understand what I was trying to say.  Did I suggest somewhere that the ability to define clockwise and counterclockwise implies CP violation? All I meant to say is that it would be impossible to communicate in some situations. I can edit what I wrote if it's unclear.